# Properties like $\sin (\cos^{-1} x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

I am doing Parametric Equations in Calculus 2 where you want to convert a system of Parametric equations into Cartesian equations without the parameter t.  By substituting
$$\theta =\cos^{-1} x$$
in the Pythagorean Identity
$$\sin^{2} \theta + \cos^{2} \theta=1$$
we get the relation:
$$\sin{(\cos^{-1} x)}=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$$
This particular identity is useful in eliminating $t$ from a system that represents a circle or an ellipse.

However, this gives me the thought that there are more identities like these (which I have seen earlier, but not paid attention to).

They don't seem to be covered in basic Trig books, but used where needed in Calculus courses.

Question 1:
Can anyone give me a list of such identities (Internet references will work equally well). Having their proofs as well would be even better, since I am not always able to derive the proof myself.

Question 2:
Where else are such identities useful? Even an example or an idea would be nice.

Comment: @coreyman317 The identities are useful. I know these trig substitutions (and have done them recently for integration). However, I am not able to connect the given substitutions in the link (which are similar to the ones in my textbook) with the above inverse trig identities. Can you help me make the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive a trig function of an inverse trig function of x.

Suppose you want $\cos (\tan^{-1} x)$.  Draw a right triangle, and label one acute angle $\theta$.  Let $\theta = \tan^{-1} x$.  So $\tan \theta = x = \frac{x}{1}$, and you can label the opposite $x$ and the adjacent $1$.  Then by the Pythagorean theorem the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$, and so $\cos \theta = $ adjacent/hypotenuse = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. This should give the correct formula for all $30$ different versions.

Comment: I like your approach. It's simple, and extensible, and doesn;t rely on recalling a ton of other trig identities.

Comment: If this triangle approach works, why do people want to do it with trig identities? You will need a different approach for each one.  This works for all 30.